# Set of points of a sequence is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of points in $\Bbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=+\infty$. Why is $$X=\left \{ x_n\ : n\in \Bbb N \right \}$$ closed.($\Bbb{R}$ has the standard topology here)

My attempt:

I am trying to show the complement is open. Let $a \in \Bbb{R}\setminus X$ then there is $N$ such that $x_n>a+1$ for $n\ge N$. Thus there are finitely many terms of the sequence $\{x_{k_1},\ldots,x_{k_j} \}$ all less than $a+1$ then $(a-1,a+1)\setminus \{x_{k_1},\ldots,x_{k_j} \}$ is a neighborhood of $a$ totally contained in  $\Bbb{R}\setminus X$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: That seems perfect, why are you not sure it's right?

Comment: I'm trying to see if this can be done using the limit points of X.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "using the limit points of $X$"? Indeed, what you have essentially shown is that $X$ has **no** limit points: for any $a \in \mathbb R$ (don't even need to exclude $X$), only finitely many points $x_n$ can be in any fixed neighborhood of $a$.

Comment: a set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is closed iff for each convergent sequence of distinct points in $A$ the limit belongs to $A$ as well. in your case the only possible limit is $\infty$ which is not in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @BaronVT I was trying to show the set is closed by showing it contains all its limit points

Comment: And thus you have shown (at least after modifying $a \in \mathbb R \backslash X$ to $a \in \mathbb R$) that $X$ has no limit points, and so the condition holds (vacuously).

Comment: A convergent sequence and its limit are always compact, in this case in the compact space $[-\infty, +\infty]$, hence closed there; so its intersection with the subspace $\mathbb{R}$ is closed. Just another way.

Comment: BaronVT is right: If you change $a\in\Bbb R\setminus X$ to $a\in\Bbb R$, you can apply almost the same method as in your post (you have to change the neighborhood to $(a-1,a+1)\setminus\{x_i\ne a\mid i=1,...,N\}$), and this shows that $a$ is not a limit point of the set $X$.